# Retrieving external image and saving locally results in distorted image

Tags: php, image-processing

Stuck on this one. I have this function below that simply takes `$ImageSrc` which is an external image from anywhere, eg imgur, and then saves it locally (this is not a scraper, I'm allowing people to attach images to their profiles)

```
public function UploadScreenshot($ImageSrc, $Title, $Description = false) {
    $RandomName = substr(md5($Title . time()), 0, 20);
    $UploadDir = "/home/vanrust/public_html/Screenshots/";

    $file = pathinfo($ImageSrc);
    $ext = $file["extension"];
    if (!in_array($ext, array('jpg','png','bmp','jpeg'))) return array("error" => "Invalid File Type");

    $RandomName = "{$RandomName}.{$ext}";
    $image = file_get_contents($ImageSrc);
    file_put_contents($UploadDir . $RandomName, $image);
}
```

The result of the file no matter what is unrecognizable.

The image:

[image]

After UploadScreenshot() has retrieved it:

[image: The result of the above script regardless of image url]

Comment: Does the file have the same length after transfer? What happens if you look at the first 100 bytes in hex - does it look like an image header?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rename() to move the original file to the new location and rename it.

```
$file = pathinfo($ImageSrc);
$ext = $file["extension"];
if (!in_array($ext, array('jpg','png','bmp','jpeg'))) return array("error" => "Invalid File Type");

$RandomName = "{$RandomName}.{$ext}";
rename($UploadDir . $RandomName, $ImageSrc);
```

}

Alternatively, you can use [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) if your $ImageSrc does contain a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism).

file_put_contents() needs to be used with caution. A single offset (in binary codes) at the beginning or at the end of the file will significantly alter the picture. It requires a validation at the end to compare both files bytes.